# Convert list of dicts to pandas columns

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column containing strings as follows:

```
"Hex:6; HexNAc:3; NeuNAc:1}"
"Fuc:1; Hex:7; HexNAc:2}"
```

I wrote the following function to convert this text into dictionaries with key value pairs as follows:

```
def create_monosacch_columns(glycan_ident):
glycans = glycan_ident.split("}")[0].split("; ")
monosaccharides = []
for entry in glycans:
    key, val = entry.split(":")
    monosacc = {key:val}
    monosaccharides.append(monosacc)
    return monosaccharides
```

output:

```
[{'Hex': '6'}, {'HexNAc': '3'}, {'NeuNAc': '1'}]
[{'Fuc': '1'}, {'Hex': '7'}, {'HexNAc': '2'}]
```

How do I convert these lists of dicts into pandas dataframe columns with the values mapping to the original rows?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you want the final output to look like, but if you don't mind having NAs you can try append your list of dictionaries as a dataframe to the original dataframe. There will be NAns, but this can be removed when you do analysis.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('HexNAc',"NeuNAc"))
```

Where the dataframe looks like this:

```
HexNAc  NeuNAc
   1       2
   3       4
```

If you look at an example list of dictionaries,

```
temp= [{'Hex': '6'}, {'HexNAc': '3'}]
```

You can then convert this list to a dataframe of its own, and append it to the dataframe you already have.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(temp)
df = df.append(df2)
```

The final list will look like this:

```
HexNAc NeuNAc
   1      2 
   3      4 
   3      NaN 
   NaN    1
```

Comment: I am not trying to create a dataframe, rather map the values in the list of dictionaries as new columns to specific rows where they are read from.

Comment: Please look at the edit to see if this matches the output you want. If not, can you please post an example of the final output?